# Why the swift language cannot provide nil to deallocate or release memory

Tags: objective-c, swift

As we work in Objective-c and when we want to deallocate or release the object we can do this for ex: NSMutableArray * arr;

```
[arr removeAllObjects];
arr = nil;
arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

we can do this and that object deallocated.

So why there is no way to do like this in swift language

we can only do this:

```
arr.removeAllObjects()
arr = NSMutableArray()
```

I am not getting how this way an object deallocate or release memory.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need your favor please provide me some links or references so I can work with optional and solve the problem

Comment: There is no need for the line `arr = nil;` in the Objective-C code you posted. And there is no need to do it in Swift either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you declare your variable as optional you can set it to `nil`.

However, with ARC you do not need to release the object by yourself (that's what ARC is for). The system will handle the memory for you when you reset the variable.

Comment: The correct term is not "will handle" but "should handle", ARC is not perfect.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano In what case ARC will *not* handle the memory (call `-release`) when you reset the variable, unless you manually make it `unowned`?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I cannot disagree with you, but let's assume that in such a simple case it will work. Otherwise you can never trust it.

Comment: @kennytm Go to openradar and search some examples, same things happen sometime in spritekit..